# NgRx: How to console.log a store.select from inside an effect?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects, ngrx-selectors

I'm learning NgRx and trying to console.log some values selected from the store inside an effect. I don't know much of RxJs. When I try, it's showing something like this, instead of a number:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
resetSample$= createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(DecisorActions.ResetSampleAction),
    map(() => { 
        this.file.readlineGuard(); // throw EOF error

        // I would like to console.log() those number values:
        console.log(this.store.select(Selectors.getA)));
        console.log(this.store.select(Selectors.getB)));
        console.log(this.store.select(Selectors.getC)));

        console.log('RESET SAMPLE EFFECT');

        return DecisorActions.BuyAction({payload: 0});
    }),
    catchError( err => { console.log('EOF detected'); return of(DecisorActions.EndOfFileError({payload:0})); })
));
```

If I'm missing some important concepts, I would also appreciate recommendations of what to read / look for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good resource to look at would be NgRx [Encorprating State](https://ngrx.io/guide/effects#incorporating-state), which uses `concatLatestFrom`. Alternatively you can use the RxJs operator `withLatestFrom`. From that NgRx link, it states:

> When state is needed, the RxJS withLatestFrom or the @ngrx/effects concatLatestFrom operators can be used to provide it.

Essentially you'd have something along the lines of:

```js
resetSample$= createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(DecisorActions.ResetSampleAction),
    withLatestFrom(
      this.store.select(Selectors.getA),
      this.store.select(Selectors.getB),
      this.store.select(Selectors.getC)
    ),
    map(([action, a, b, c]) => { 
        this.file.readlineGuard(); // throw EOF error

        // Log values here:
        console.log(a);
        console.log(b);
        console.log(c);

        console.log('RESET SAMPLE EFFECT');

        return DecisorActions.BuyAction({payload: 0});
    }),
    catchError( err => { console.log('EOF detected'); return of(DecisorActions.EndOfFileError({payload:0})); })
));
```

**Note:** If using version 6 of RxJS, only 5 arguments are allowed within `withLatestFrom`. See [this](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/5221) Github issue.

Starting from version 7, the code was updated to allow any number of arguments. See the code for the operator [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/withLatestFrom.ts).

Comment: there's an extra ) at getA)),  and so on, in the example

Comment: btw, I just discoverd that if you try to use more than 5 arguments inside WithLatesFrom, it breaks

Comment: reference for the problem of more than 5 arguments: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/5221

Comment: Good catch on the max number of arguments for `withLatestFrom`! I'll edit my answer to call that out for others. Once there's more than 2-3 arguments, at that point is when I'd strongly consider creating a new selector to get the information I need.

Comment: @JoãoOtero, looking more at withLatestFrom, that was updated in v. 7 to accept more arguments rather than being hardcoded to 5. I'll post that in my answer as well.

Comment: another question: what is the 'action' at the beginning of the map function?

Comment: @JoãoOtero the action is the action that is being piped into this effect which is the first line with `ofType(DecisorAction.ResetSampleAction)`. So you can use the `action` variable to access any information that may be on the action.